# Capture video from android camera with gstreamer

Tags: android, camera, gstreamer

Does anybody know how to capture video from android camera and save it to file using gstreamer1.0? I have already tried  `camerabin` plugin. I built this pipeline: 
`gst-launch-1.0 camerabin mode=1 filename="/storage/sdcard0/Movies/camera.ogg"` 
but it doesn't work. I uderstand that I must set `viewfinder-sink` and `camera-src` properties, but when I try to make pipeline by using gstreamer functions  like this

```
 `data->pipeline = gst_element_factory_make("camerabin", "camerabin");
 g_object_set(data->pipeline, "mode", MODE_VIDEO, NULL);
 sink = gst_element_factory_make ("filesink", NULL);
 g_object_set(sink, "location","/storage/sdcard0/Movies/test.ogg");
 g_object_set(data->pipeline, "viewfinder-sink", sink, NULL);
 g_object_set(data->pipeline, "filename","/storage/sdcard0/Movies/camera-record.ogg", NULL);
 gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);`
```

the app crashes and gives me error:

`A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x83127d5b in tid 27873 (als.tutorial_51)`
I add filesink element because when I build pipeline like this:

```
data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch("camerabin mode=1 filename="/storage/sdcard0/Movies/camera.ogg")
```

file camera.ogg doesn't create in filesystem.

And I can't set `camera-src` property, because i don't know what value i should use. In examples peoples use `v4l2`, but not all devices support this plugin. Also they used `ahcsrc`, but it gives me error: `no elements ahcsrc`. I tried to find this element and found out there is no such element in gstreamer1.0, only in gstreamer-0.10 in `androidcamera` plugin.

Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

The ahcsrc plugin does exist in gstreamer 1.0.  It was added in gstreamer 1.8 to the "bad" plugins.

You should use the theoraenc plugin to encode to .ogv video.

Comment: Can you give me link with tutorial how to install bad plugin in gstreamer sdk?  I should say I compile gstreamer library every time when  compile my project. I do it with gradle.